# How do I perform sequence labeling in caffe using LSTM

Tags: sequence, caffe, lstm, labeling

I have looked at the LRCN example (http://tutorial.caffe.berkeleyvision.org/caffe-cvpr15-sequences.pdf) which use LSTM for classification. For video classification a majority voting is done. Why is that? I would assume one waits until the end of a sequence?

In my toy, example binary counting, I inputted the labels in two different ways.
First I labelled every timestep with the sequence label. Secondly I labelled every timestep with an ignore_label but the last one. For simplicity I used a sequence length of 50 and a batchsize of 50 as well.
Both approaches lead to a network, where when I deploy it, I receive the same output for every timestep.

**Edit**:
The toy example works, if instead of classifying a whole sequence, one predicts the next number. Thus for each number a label exists. This is no solution for a real-world sequence classification task. Using the post by Kaparthy (http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/) I have created following network:

```
name: "BasicLstm"

layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "cont"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "./path_to_txt.txt"
    batch_size: 2000
  }
}


layer {
  name: "lstm1"
  type: "LSTM"
  bottom: "data"
  bottom: "cont"
  top: "lstm1"
  recurrent_param {
    num_output: 5
    weight_filler {
      type: "uniform"
      min: -0.08
      max: 0.08
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}

layer {
  name: "lstm2"
  type: "LSTM"
  bottom: "lstm1"
  bottom: "cont"
  top: "lstm2"
  recurrent_param {
    num_output: 4
    weight_filler {
      type: "uniform"
      min: -0.08
      max: 0.08
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}


layer {
  name: "predict"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "lstm2"
  top: "predict"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 39
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
    axis: 2
  }
}



layer {
  name: "softmax_loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "predict"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
  loss_weight: 20
  softmax_param {
    axis: 2
  }
  loss_param {
    ignore_label: -1
  }
}
```

The important parts of the solver: I already have played a little bit with `lr_policy: INV` but in the end I tried it with fixed

```
net: "Basic.prototxt"
test_initialization: false
base_lr: 0.001
momentum: 0.9
lr_policy: "fixed"
display: 50
max_iter: 1000000
solver_mode: GPU
```

- No sequence ranges over 2000.
- I have put 10 sequences side by side.
- I embedded my data in a one hot vector of size 132.
- My data HDF5 file has these dimensions: XX*10*132*1
- My data has a label at the end of each sequence. Every other label is -1 and will be ignored during backpropagation.
- To increase efficiency I packed multiple short sequences together (they are below 2000 timesteps).

For classification I have used the python interface. When I classify a sequence following arises:

```
net.blobs['data'].reshape(726, 1, 132, 1)
net.blobs['cont'].reshape(726, 1)

net.blobs['data'].data[...] = data
net.blobs['cont'].data[...] = cont

output = net.forward()
output_prob = output['prob']

for i in range(726):
    plt.plot(output_prob[i][0])
```

[image: One can see that for every timestep, the same output has been predicted]

In the image one can see that for every timestep the same probabilities have been calculated.

Comment: Hi, I still haven't got the LRCN version of caffe to work for me. If possible could you share the sequence _input_layer.py file ?

Comment: Hello, I have not tried the LRCN example. I am still wondering how to do sequence classification.

Comment: Can u add the code for the binary counting example. Maybe someone with experience can find a bug/improvement to fix ur issue.